# bind unbind dynamically $document click event in angular JS custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, mouseclick-event

I want to bind body click event to custom directive. I have created a custom directive for drop down. My functionality is I want closed the option list when the user clicks on the body. The html code for drop down is created by using `<ul>` and `<li>` tag. I have used the directive several times on the page. but the page now became slow as the no. of usage of directive increased on the page. So i want to know how to dynamically bind and unbind body click event inside the directive. i used `$document.bind('click',function(){//function body});`  syntax to bind click event. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a soft limit about about 2,000 watches. If you are showing tabular data or binding lots of smaller pieces of data that limit is not hard to reach. This is more likely the issue. Event handlers are not anywhere near as expensive as a watch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JQuery, you can use the link method to manipulate DOM elements and add listeners

See : [the AngularJS doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-adds-event-listeners)

I hope it may help